# Revert commits made by merging of a certain branch in master

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have a branch called tempMaster and my team is continuously merging their feature branch changed on this tempmaster branch and then merging this tempmaster into master.But i found that a certain user has merged his feature branch accidentally in the tempmaster and then he also merged this tempmaster with master. There are multiple merge made by the user in tempmaster and then tempmaster into master. I need to revert al the changes which has been made by merging his feature branch into tempmaster and then tempmaster into master.

I can see the history by following command

```
git log --author=imran.zafar@bharatconnect.com --pretty=one --since=30.days
```

But this only show me the commit made by the user in past one month but i am not sure when he merged his feature branch for the first time.Is there any git command by which i can revert all the commit which has been generated by the merging this feature branch into master?

Comment: You need to show us some branch structure.  Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: You want to revert the latest commit you pushed?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I want to revert all the commits which had been made by merging that feature branch.

Comment: You can revert all the commits made by that author, that is what you want?

Comment: But that might revert other commits as well which had been made by that user but not by infected feature branch

Comment: @AtulAgrawal So you just need to **revert** the changes merged on `master` branch while **keeping** the changes on `feature` branch and changes merged on `tempmaster` branch?

Comment: yes...it will also help

Comment: @AtulAgrawal Did you revert the commits on master branch successful?

Answer (score 0):

To revert the merged commits on `master` branch by the user, you can use below steps:

#### 1.   Find which commits are merged into master branch by the user

Use any of the belwo commands to show the commit history as a graph, and then find the merged commits on master branch by the user.

```
gitk --all
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

#### 2.   Revert the found commits from new to old on `master` branch

Assume the commit history as below garph. The commits `F2` and `F4` on `feature` branch were committed by the user, the commits `T3` and `T4` on `tempmaster` branch were the merged commits that the user merge `feature` branch into `tempmaster`, the commits `M2` and `M3` on `master` branch were merged by the user.

```
       …---M1---M2------…-----M3---…    master
               /             /
…---T1---T2---T3-----…------T4 ---…     tempmaster
        /    /             /
…-----F1---F2---…---F3---F4---…         feature
```

So you should revert the commits `M2` and `M3` on master branch.

First revert the newer commit `M3` by `git revert -m 1 <commit id for M3>`. The `-m 1` option means keep the changes from the first parent and revert the changes from second parent (commit `T4`) on `master` branch. Then the commit history will be:

```
       …---M1---M2------…-----M3---…---M3'    master
               /             /
…---T1---T2---T3-----…------T4 ---…          tempmaster
        /    /             /
…-----F1---F2---…---F3---F4---…              feature
```

Now the changes introduced by `T4` has been reverted as commit `M3'` on master branch.

Then revert the older merged commit `M2` on `master` branch by `git revert -m 1 <commit id for M2>`. And the commit history will be:

```
       …---M1---M2------…-----M3---…---M3'---M2'    master
               /             /
…---T1---T2---T3-----…------T4 ---…          tempmaster
        /    /             /
…-----F1---F2---…---F3---F4---…              feature
```

And the changes introduced by `T3` has been reverted by the commit `M2'` on `master` branch.